# Using both OOP and Function programming paradims

Tags: oop, functional-programming

I read about OOP and Function programming. And I found both have pros and cons.
Such as:

- OOP: have side effect, and sometimes it is very usefull
- Function: easy to code and think. But don't have side effect and loop.

And I wonder if I can using both OOP and Function paradigm in one project. Is it be recommended in practice?

Comment: pretty much every JS project is based on a mix of those two paradigms

Comment: @PatrykCieszkowski yes, I usually use both

Comment: Highly recommend learning Functional Reactive Programming, will replace any need you have for OOP and side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing preventing both paradigms from being used together. Arguments on each side sometimes can be misleading as people tend to focus on languages and their features as opposed to the paradigms themselves. OOP doesn't *need* to have state/side effects, and functional programming doesn't always make things easier or faster. The good engineer will use the right tools for the right task, which means getting a good understanding of both.

Comment: yes, that is right, depending on task and project